# A Nullreferenceexception was unhandledby user code. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a column fields with different names. For example I load the files from ABC. and the Name column fields will be ABC.

I have to show a button only when I select the ABC row object.

I wrote a code below, but its throwing an exception. It would be great helpful if someone suggest me on this.

```
FormViewButton fvb = FormViewButton.getInstance();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;


            bool selectedRow = row.Cells["Name"].Selected;

            if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().Equals("ABC") && selectedRow == true) // A Nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code is thrown here. 
            {
                fmv.showButton.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (!row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().Equals("ABC") && selectedRow != true)
            { 
                fmv.showButton.Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because either `row.Cells["Name"]` or `row.Cells["Name"].Value` doesn't exist.

**Solution**: When you iterate through `Rows` of your `DataGridView`, check indexes:

- if `RowIndex == -1` then it's a header row
- if `RowIndex` == [dataGridView1.NewRowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.newrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) then its a new row, and the cell's `Value` will be `null`

... and check if `row.Cells["Name"] != null && row.Cells["Name"].Value != null`, just in case

Comment: Thank you. Its well explained and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if a cell or string variable is null and you try to attach some string method to it, such as something.ToString() or something.indexof etc., C# will always throw a null exception error.